# Running scipy optimize yields attribute-error

Tags: python

I'm trying to use scipy optimize with the minimize function to find the values of my two guessed variables that minimizes the function, I'm currently running it like this:

```
def function_to_min(theta):
    respons = responsibilities()[0][0][0]
    sequence_to_foc = sequence[0][0][0]
    pis = calculating_pis()[0]
    return np.nan_to_num((-1)*(respons * np.log(pis*get_emission(theta[0], sequence_to_foc, theta[1]))))

theta2 = np.array([mu_initial2, sigma_guess])

res = minimize(function_to_min, theta2, method='nelder-mead',
options = {'xtol': 2, 'disp': True})
print(res.theta)
```

I haven't posted all the code I can print the result of the values, everything it currently single valued (no arrays). Why do I keep getting raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: theta ?

Comment: the `res.theta` in the end of the code cause this I guess. According to scipy document. the return of optimize is https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.OptimizeResult.html#scipy.optimize.OptimizeResult.
which means you should `print(res.x)` instead

Comment: You're right, this fixed my problem, I'm grateful for your help but my personal ego takes this like a punch... Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the res.theta in the end of the code cause this I guess. According to scipy document. the return of optimize is docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/…. which means you should print(res.x) instead.